# returning a rxjs observable from a function of a class that implements an adapter

Tags: typescript, rxjs, rxjs-observables

I get the error:

```
    Type 'Observable<string>' is missing the following properties from type 'Observable<string>': _isScalar, _trySubscribe, _subscribets(2416)
```

I abstracted the code I'm trying to write in the playground. yet there is no sign of any error in the play ground, somehow I have it on my code. typescript version 4.6.2. rxjs version 7.5.1

```
import { Observable, interval, map } from 'rxjs'

interface Adapter {
    subscribeToMessage(): Observable<string>;
}

class myMessenger implements Adapter {
    constructor() { }
    subscribeToMessage(): Observable<string> {
        return interval(1000).pipe(map(() => 'a message'))
    }
}
```

**Output**

```
import { interval, map } from 'rxjs';
class myMessenger {
    constructor() { }
    subscribeToMessage() {
        return interval(1000).pipe(map(i => 'the number ' + i + ' message'));
    }
}
```

**Compiler Options**

```json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "strict": true,
    "noImplicitAny": true,
    "strictNullChecks": true,
    "strictFunctionTypes": true,
    "strictPropertyInitialization": true,
    "strictBindCallApply": true,
    "noImplicitThis": true,
    "noImplicitReturns": true,
    "alwaysStrict": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "declaration": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "target": "ES2017",
    "jsx": "react",
    "module": "ESNext",
    "moduleResolution": "node"
  }
}
```

**Playground Link:** [Provided](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAbzgeQEYGcCmUBuBDVAG0wBo5gA7GbfQskPMOAXzgDMoIQ4ByKADwBW6HgChRlalDZ4AxpjgBBACaMpiUXC1x0AVwyyowVJgAqEALKZ06PAHNMACgCUALhQYaBYgB50MIwo7AD4AblFmcVlCPBs4EABPKxtMIOxycGIQVJh0JVUwdQRNbVkICn8oXVkYaBdEFhKtPQMjE3Nk2wcXdzQsXG9MPwDKEI1tCbgoTBhdKApyKi9CRwBGAAZN5wA6MGAwJwYwR2A4AF5g3hgACwUKXRATKF44AGpyN5fsm3tMHmdnE1GpEgA)

I tried the documentation of Rxjs about the observables and the subscriptions. I know the pipe function returns an observable and I expect the code have no error as it is in the playground.
I don't know what I miss or if any of my configs are wrong. I'm using typescript version 4.6.2 and rxjs version 7.5.1

Comment: By the way, code is working by ignoring the error though `// @ts-ignore`

Comment: I tried the code in Stackblitz and didn't get an error. (I added a take so it didn't run forever.) https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-lhjbpm But personally, I never use Observable<T> as a data type in an interface. Is there another way to accomplish your objective? If you are trying to create a multi-cast Observable, try using a Subject instead.

Comment: @DeborahK Thank you so much for your time. It appeared to be caused by a dependency conflict. I also didn't get any error on the abstract project. At the time I couldn't think of anything. After a nap I see through it and checked the dependencies.
Thank you again and appreciate your precious time

Comment: now I realize that I didn't mention that I use npm workspaces in my question. I'm sorry!

Comment: @DeborahK I'm trying to listen to a socket connection and emit the messages to another socket connection. I couldn't think of a better solution. Hence the messages aren't interval over a fixed timeout and are provided by a third party. Also I find this approach very satisfying since I unsubscribe to the observer on socket closing! I use subjects too on sending this observable to the second socket, yet for getting messages from the first socket I'm setting an observable though

Answer (score 0):

After some serious investigation and reading lots of similar problems on the web.
I figured it should be because of different referencing and guess what! I have concurrently that has a different version of rxjs installed by it's own and my code actually uses two separate types, one for definition and another for implementation (because scopes are different) and that causes the types be so different!

> I use npm workspace though! npm@8

```
$ npm ls rxjs

+-- concurrently@7.0.0
| `-- rxjs@6.6.7
`-- services@1.0.0 -> .\services
  `-- rxjs@7.5.5
```

So I installed rxjs on the higher scope `npm install rxjs@7.5.5 --save-dev` and the problem solved! The result is like:

```
$ npm ls rxjs

+-- concurrently@7.0.0
| `-- rxjs@6.6.7
+-- rxjs@7.5.5
`-- services@1.0.0 -> .\services
  `-- rxjs@7.5.5 deduped
```